# İ have problem with nodejs i dont take data ,Error is Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Tags: node.js, codeigniter

I used guzzlehttp following the bottom source ,I want to send total to nodejs .But nodejs gives error  code line 8 => console.log(req.body.total) is that error "Cannot read property 'total' of undefined"

```
//codeighter
1  $response = $this->guzzle->request('get', 'http://localhost:1881/Onlineusers2', ['total' =>11]);


//Nodejs
1  const express = require('express');
2  const app = express();
3  const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

4  exports.Onlineusers2 = function (req, res) {
5    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
6        socket.broadcast.emit("total", 1991);
7    });
8    console.log(req.body.total);
9    res.status(200).json({ msg: success });
10
11  };
```

I got this error Cannot read property 'total' of undefined" Nodejs line 8
How can i get data post or get over guzzlehttp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to configure your app .js like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.get("/Onlineusers2", function(req, res) {
   io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.broadcast.emit("total", 1991);
   });
   console.log(req.body.total);
});
```

I hope this works:))

Comment: I got same problem  Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Comment: what are you getting if you print req.body

Comment: // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass any data to `get` api call.

Use `query params` or  `post` call